# Paypal recurring plan update/Cancel

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I have a website through which user can set recurring Paypal payments. Issue which I am facing :
- Can I cancel a user's plan from my website through API?
- Can I update a user's recurring plan through API? for eg he may give $10 first month but then he decides to give $50 for the upcoming months. Is this possible via API ?

Comment: Are you using Standard Subscription buttons or the actual Recurring Payments APIs?  Are you working with Classic NVP/SOAP API or REST?

Comment: I wish to use REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the REST API you can do everything you're wanting using [Billing Agreements](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-agreement/) and/or [Billing Plans](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-plan/).